# R dplyr with seq()

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to mutate a column in a dataframe, with the seq of another column.
For example with `iris`, I would like to add a new column for each Species, with
`seq(min(Sepal.Length),max(Sepal.Length),length=100)`

I tried (with no success):

```
 iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     mutate(seqq = seq(min(Sepal.Length),max(Sepal.Length),  100))
```

Any ideas?

thank you!

Comment: Each `Species` has 50 rows, so `mutate`ing a column with 100 elements in it makes no sense. Please provide what you expect the output to look like. (Do you mean `summarize` instead of `mutate`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutate` needs to return the same number of rows as the original data or the ones in the group_by.  We may use `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise(seq = seq(min(Sepal.Length),max(Sepal.Length), 
         length = 100), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 300 x 2
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Species   seq
   <fct>   <dbl>
 1 setosa   4.3 
 2 setosa   4.32
 3 setosa   4.33
 4 setosa   4.35
 5 setosa   4.36
 6 setosa   4.38
 7 setosa   4.39
 8 setosa   4.41
 9 setosa   4.42
10 setosa   4.44
# … with 290 more rows
```